# Drupal form submit action changing at random times

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a custom Drupal module/form that when submitted the action takes you to another page and posts data with it. Pretty standard stuff.

Randomly, the form action changes at random (not set) intervals during the day that are not correlating to anything immediately obvious - for example cron runs. It only happens maybe once or twice a day, so if anyone has any idea what might cause this or point me in the right direction.

Anything anyone feels needs adding, let me know.

The is the custom module code:

```
/**
 * Test form declaration
 */

function test_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form['#attributes'] = array('id' => "test-form");
    $form['search-field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('<span class="highlighted">Test</span>'),
    '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('form-control form-text'),
        ),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Search',
    '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('btn btn-default text-hide'),
      ),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
 * search form submit
 */
function test_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $searchQuery = $form_state['values']['search-field'];


$query = array();
if($search <> ''){
    $query = array(
        'field_geofield_distance[distance]' => '100',
        'field_geofield_distance[unit]' => '3959',
        'field_geofield_distance[origin]' => $search
    );
}
drupal_goto('test-page', array('query' => $query));
}
```

Comment: What does the form action change to?

Comment: Maybe I need to change my question - it's the value that changes. The URL that page is supposed redirect to changes to a completely random page that doesn't exist on the site.

Comment: oh, so sometimes it does not redirect to 'test-page' ? Where does it go to?

Comment: yes, 95% of the it does.

The site has replaced by another, complete rebuild and strangely enough the redirects are going to existing pages on the old website, which I can categorically say is not there any more.

Comment: hmm, maybe there is a form_alter doing something somewhere. Check the values of $form_state in your submit function. Check that `$form_state['redirect']` is not set. Also check $_GET['destination'] is not set.

Comment: Thanks 2pha, I'll look into that now.

Comment: @2pha Just got back around to this. I have just checked ['redirect'] and it is not set. Is there a way to check if drupal_goto goes to 'test-page' and if not make sure it does?

Answer (score 1):

If your form creates data (let's say a node) possibly you have a redirection on rules when creating a node that with specific values redirects to another page.

Look for rules that are activated when content creation occur or when submission occur.

Also you could have some redirection magic in the top of Drupal, like a wrong configuration of an .htacess file. If your form does the same thing always it should behave the same always. And why it's redirecting to page of old site?

Finally, if the new site have code from the old site the check submission, creation and form altering hooks.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Beto. I will take look through the .htaccess file, you could be onto something there. It's a really strange one, I have not come across anything like this before.

I don't think the form creates data.